# Counting different kinds of line terminator characters in files

Tags: regex, file, go

Can someone take a look if this code piece is ok. I'm most interested whether the goroutines are used correctly, but also general Go best practices.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "regexp"
)

type Endings struct {
    crlf, lf uint
}

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}

func getFileList(searchDir string) []string {
    fileList := []string{}
    filepath.Walk(searchDir, func(path string, f os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if !f.IsDir() {
            fileList = append(fileList, path)
        }
        return nil
    })

    return fileList
}

func getFileEndings(filename string, c chan Endings) {
    fileContent, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    check(err)
    c <- countEndings(string(fileContent))
}

func countEndings(s string) Endings {
    crlf := regexp.MustCompile("\r\n")
    lf := regexp.MustCompile("\n")

    x := len(crlf.FindAllStringIndex(s, -1))
    y := len(lf.FindAllStringIndex(s, -1))

    return Endings{uint(x), uint(y - x)}
}

func splitIntoChunks(arr []string, chunkSize int) [][]string {
    if chunkSize <= 0 {
        panic("chunk size too small")
    }

    if len(arr) <= chunkSize {
        return [][]string{arr}
    }

    numChunks := int(len(arr)/chunkSize) + 1
    chunks := make([][]string, numChunks)

    for i := 0; i < numChunks; i++ {
        l := i * chunkSize
        u := l + chunkSize

        if u > len(arr) {
            u = len(arr)
        }

        chunks[i] = arr[l:u]
    }

    return chunks
}

func main() {
    searchDir := os.Args[1]
    c := make(chan Endings)
    chunkSize := 1000

    fileList := getFileList(searchDir)

    count := Endings{0, 0}
    for _, chunk := range splitIntoChunks(fileList, chunkSize) {
        for _, file := range chunk {
            go getFileEndings(file, c)
        }

        for _ = range chunk {
            result := <-c

            count.crlf += result.crlf
            count.lf += result.lf
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("crlf: %d, lf: %d\n", count.crlf, count.lf)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program works fine and you are correctly using goroutines, but the code isn't very idiomatic.

### Producer/Consumer architecture

What we have here is a typical producer/consumer scenario. The producer is `filepath.Walk()` wich returns a list of files, and the consumers are goroutines executing `regex` on file content.

So instead of the `splitIntoChunks()` method, we could just have a **`chan string`**: the producer sends file names to the channel, and the consumers loop over it and parse the file content.

This have two main advantages:

- code is easier to read
- producer and consumer can work in parallel

So the code would looks like

```
results := make(chan Endings, 2) // chan to get the results of each worker
var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(2)
files := make(chan string, 1000) // channel containing file list
for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
    go run(files, results, &wg) // start the producers 
}
filepath.Walk(searchDir, func(path string, f os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    if !f.IsDir() {
        files <- path // feed the channel
    }
    return nil
})
close(files)
wg.Wait()
close(results)
```

### Work on []byte rather than on string

This is a general advice regarding performances: always prefer working on `[]byte` instead of working on `string` to avoid extra allocations. 
The regex package has methods to work on string or on byte slice, so instead of

```
fileContent, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
c <- countEndings(string(fileContent)) 
...
x := len(crlf.FindAllStringIndex(s, -1))
```

we can just use

```
fileContent, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fileName)
...
x := len(crlf.FindAllIndex(fileContent, -1))
```

### Don't panic

The code shouldn't panic on every error. For example, if the user running the program don't have the permission to read a file in `searchDir`, the program should not crash but rather log the error

so avoid method like this:

```
func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}
```

instead handle the error localy:

```
fileContent, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fileName)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("fail to read file %s: %v\n", fileName, err)
}
```

### Other consideration

It's better to define regex as global var:

```
var (
    crlf = regexp.MustCompile("\r\n")
    lf   = regexp.MustCompile("\n")
)
```

It's also better to use the `flag` package to parse arguments instead of relying on `os.Args`

Here is the final version of the code:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "regexp"
    "sync"
)

var (
    crlf = regexp.MustCompile("\r\n")
    lf   = regexp.MustCompile("\n")
)

type Endings struct {
    crlf, lf uint
}

func (e *Endings) countEndings(fileName string) {
    c, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fileName)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("fail to read file %s: %v\n", fileName, err)
    }
    x := len(crlf.FindAllIndex(c, -1))
    y := len(lf.FindAllIndex(c, -1))

    e.crlf += uint(x)
    e.lf += uint(y - x)
}

func run(files <-chan string, results chan<- Endings, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    e := &Endings{}
    for f := range files {
        e.countEndings(f)
    }
    results <- *e
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {

    searchDir := flag.String("dir", "dir", "directory to search")
    nWorker := flag.Int("n", 2, "number of worker")
    flag.Parse()

    results := make(chan Endings, *nWorker)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(*nWorker)
    files := make(chan string, 1000)
    for i := 0; i < *nWorker; i++ {
        go run(files, results, &wg)
    }
    filepath.Walk(*searchDir, func(path string, f os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if !f.IsDir() {
            files <- path
        }
        return nil
    })
    close(files)
    wg.Wait()
    close(results)

    count := &Endings{}
    for e := range results {
        count.crlf += e.crlf
        count.lf += e.lf
    }
    fmt.Printf("crlf: %d, lf: %d\n", count.crlf, count.lf)
}
```

### Performance

The new code is slightly faster:

**old:**

```
$ time ./test ~/go/src/golang.org          
crlf: 6231, lf: 1589462
./test ~/go/src/golang.org  1,78s user 0,23s system 167% cpu 1,201 total
```

**new:**

```
$ time ./test -dir ~/go/src/golang.org -n 6 
crlf: 6231, lf: 1589462
./test -dir ~/go/src/golang.org -n 6  1,48s user 0,18s system 181% cpu 0,911 total
```